# ASP.NET: How to change the background color of a control that failed validation?

Tags: asp.net, validation

Let's take the following simple site as an example:

```
<asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" 
runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp; 
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
id="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
ErrorMessage="Required!" 
ControlToValidate="TextBox1">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Now, I would want the `TextBox1` to change its `BackColor` to yellow when ever the validation has failed. Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Page.Validators is a ValidatorCollection.  You can iterate this collection casting each member to BaseValidator.  Check BaseValidator.IsValid and get the name of the control from BaseValidator.ControlToValidate.  Use this.FindControl(control name) to get a reference to the control (this returns a Control object).  Perform whatever type checking and casting you need to do, and then if you can cast the control to TextBox or some other control that contains the BackColor property, cast it and set the BackColor.

Here's a simplified version:

```
   private void setInvalidControlsBackColor()
    {
        Control c;
        TextBox t;
        foreach (BaseValidator v in Page.Validators)
        {
            if (!v.IsValid)
            {
                c = (Control)this.FindControl(v.ControlToValidate);
                // check the type, make sure you can cast this...
                t = (TextBox)c;
                t.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                // or however else you want to handle this...
            }
        }
    }
```

The reason I didn't include code for the type checking stuff is because you may want to handle the different control types differently, etc.  Also, if you're not using the ToolTip fields on your validators, you can use this field to store additional info (kind of like the Tag property).  That might be considered ugly practice, but it's there for you if you need it...can be used as a hint of what to do with valid/invalid states.

Comment: My page has text boxes as well as dropdown boxes. When downcasting from Control (to either a TextBox or a Dropdown) - how can we dynamically determine whether we need to downcast to a TextBox or a Dropdown (because the validation could have failed for either).

Comment: @bflemi3 This question and answer were from more than three years ago, but I believe the pattern is to call Page.Validate() in code when the user submits the form, and then after that all of the BaseValidators in Page.Validators will be set and you can call this kind of method immediately after Page.Validate().  I think that's how it works...I haven't done any ASP.NET programming in about three years now, and I don't know if anything is different now in MVC

Comment: @Rich in serverside validation code, how to restore the textbox's back color to default back color of TextBox if validation is ok? Do we have to keep the back color value before changing it to Color.Yellow?

Answer (score 1):

A better option would be to inherit from the system validators and create your own validators. You can override the default behavior to change the background color of the ControlToValidate field. For most controls you don't need to check the type, you can just set the style value to "background-color:yellow".

Comment: I had tought of that, but wanted to ask if there were some alternative solutions.